# Exporting DataGridView records to Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with several columns and different report types, where I have a method to export the records to Excel spreadsheet, in this datagridview I leave some columns like: `visible = false` according to the selected report type.

In the export method for spreadsheet I have a validation to consider only visible cells, true but it is not working.

```
        int XLRow = 1;
        int XLCol = 1;

        // Export header
        for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (datagrid.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = datagrid.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }

        XLRow = 2;
        XLCol = 1;

        // Controls for scrolling through records do DataGridView
        for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < datagrid.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = datagrid[j, i];
                string conteudo = string.Empty;
                if ((cell.Value != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString())) && cell.Visible == true)
                {
                    conteudo = cell.Value.ToString();
                    if ((Funcoes.EhNumerico(conteudo)) && (conteudo.Length > 8))
                    {
                        conteudo = string.Concat("'", conteudo);
                    }
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = conteudo;
                }
                XLRow++;
                XLCol = 1;
            }
        }
```

The spreadsheet leaves with the columns that are `visible = false` in white, as follows:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The spreadsheet is not receiving the not-visible gridview columns; you are putting the visible gridview columns in the wrong spreadsheet columns.

Comment: In the first for loop through the columns, the code checks to see if that column is visible and if it IS, then add the header. The problem with this is that since you are using `i` as an index to the worksheet, the invisible column may be skipped, however, the index `i` is STILL incremented… meaning the next column will be using `i` + 1 and this is why you see the blank columns in the Excel file. This same idea applies to the code that adds the grids cells. I suggest you make a couple of `int` variables “just” for the Excel indexes and use `i`, `j` strictly as the indexes into the grid cells….

Comment: But wouldn't I store the values ​​of i and j in these suggested variables? could you help me visualize the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words… in the first `for` loop… if the column is not visible… then you DO NOT want to increment `i`… and this is obviously going to mess up the `for` loop. Hence my suggestion to create two (2) `int` variables… `int XLRow` and `int XLColumn`, then use those indexes specifically for the WORKSHEET. Then loop through the grid columns as your code does using `i` and `j`, however, when a column is found that is not visible, then you DO NOT want to increment the `XLCol` index.

It will be a challenging juggling the `loops` `i` or `j` variables to also be used as an index into the worksheet columns as they may be completely “different” indexes. This is why I say “separate” them from the git go and keep it simple. Something like…

***EDIT per OP comment…***

I had the code that “increments” the `XLCol` “INSIDE” the `if` statement that checks for a `null` cell value or an empty string cell value… meaning if the cell is `null` or empty… then `XLCol` does not get incremented. The line `xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = conteudo;` should be “outside” that `if` statement. I have edited the code and it should work properly now with “empty” cells.

```
int XLRow = 1;
int XLCol = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Columns.Count; i++) {
  if (datagrid.Columns[i].Visible == true)
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = datagrid.Columns[i].HeaderText;
}
XLRow = 2;
XLCol = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.RowCount; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < datagrid.ColumnCount; j++) {
    if (datagrid.Columns[j].Visible) {
      DataGridViewCell cell = datagrid[j, i];
      string conteudo = string.Empty;
      if ((cell.Value != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))) {
        conteudo = cell.Value.ToString();
        if ((Funcoes.EhNumerico(conteudo)) && (conteudo.Length > 8)) {
          conteudo = string.Concat("'", conteudo);
        }
        //xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = conteudo; <- XLCol incremented ONLY if cell is not null or empty and this is wrong
      }
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[XLRow, XLCol++] = conteudo;
    }
  }
  XLRow++;
  XLCol = 1;
}
```

Comment: The header came correct with your suggestion, however I couldn't organize the records, which came messy one under the other, I added a photo for you to view.

Comment: Sorry I did not test this... please give me a moment to test it. In the meantime, can you add the code with your changes?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help. I updated the code.

Comment: @Favieri ... sorry... I should have tested this first. The updated code now works as expected.

Comment: It's working, I appreciate it, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @Favieri ... Glad you got it working... I had the last two lines of code incrementing inside the column loop and it should be outside the column loop…. Sorry about that. Also as a heads up… it is better if you “ADD” your updated code to the question with something like an “EDIT” header and explain the additional updated code as opposed to “deleting” the existing code. Deleting the previous code may confuse others who may read the comments. Example, if you read my 2nd comment now… It makes no sense when looking at the current code. Just a heads up.

Comment: I will take advice on the question. Regarding the code, it worked partially, I have a second problem, if in my grid I have all the columns with the information filled in, it shows the spreadsheet correctly, but if I have some blank information, it doesn't fill the column with the blank information, it takes the information from the next column, making everything messy.

Comment: @Favieri ... Thanks for pointing out my error, I have updated the code in my answer to properly increment `XLCol`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community, you helped me a lot!